# String together awk commands

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I'm writing a script that searches a file, gets info that it then stores into variables, and executes a program that I made using those variables as data. I actually have all of that working, but I need to take it a step further:

What I currently have is

```
    #!/bin/sh                                                                       
    START=0                                                                         
    END=9                                                                           
    LOOP=10                                                                         
    PASS=0                                                                          
    for i in $(seq 0 $LOOP)                                                         
    do                                                                              
        LEN=$(awk '/Len =/ { print $3; exit;}' ../../Tests/shabittestvectors/SHA1ShortMsg.rsp)
        MSG=$(awk '/Msg =/ { print $3; exit; }' ../../Tests/shabittestvectors/SHA1ShortMsg.rsp)
        MD=$(awk '/MD =/ { print $3; exit; }' ../../Tests/shabittestvectors/SHA1ShortMsg.rsp)

        echo $LEN                                                                   
        echo $MSG                                                                   
        MD=${MD:0:-1}                                                               
        CIPHER=$(./cyassl hash -sha -i $MSG -l $LEN)                                
        echo $MD                                                                    
        echo $CIPHER                                                                

        if [ $MD == $CIPHER ]; then                                                 
            echo "PASSED"                                                           
            PASS=$[PASS + 1]                                                        
            echo $PASS                                                              
        fi                                                                          
    done                                                                            
    if [ $PASS == $[LOOP+1] ]; then                                                 
        echo "All Tests Successful"                                                 
    fi
```

And the input file looks like this:

```
Len = 0
Msg = 00
MD = da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709

Len = 1
Msg = 00
MD = bb6b3e18f0115b57925241676f5b1ae88747b08a

Len = 2
Msg = 40
MD = ec6b39952e1a3ec3ab3507185cf756181c84bbe2
```

All the program does right now, is read the first instances of the variables and loop around there. I'm hoping to use `START` and `END` to determine the lines in which it checks the file, and then increment them every time it loops to obtain the other instances of the variable names, but all of my attempts have been unsuccessful so far. Any ideas?

EDIT: Output should look something like, providing my program "./cyassl" works as it should

```
0
00
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
PASSED

1
00
bb6b3e18f0115b57925241676f5b1ae88747b08a
bb6b3e18f0115b57925241676f5b1ae88747b08a                    
PASSED

2
40
ec6b39952e1a3ec3ab3507185cf756181c84bbe2
ec6b39952e1a3ec3ab3507185cf756181c84bbe2
PASSED

etc.
```

Comment: To illustrate what you want, would you show some sample output?

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to make multiple passes on the input file.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec < ../../Tests/shabittestvectors/SHA1ShortMsg.rsp
status=pass
awk '{print $3,$6,$9}' RS= | {
while read len msg md; do
    if test "$(./cyassl hash -sha -i $msg -l $len)" = "$md"; then
        echo passed
    else
        status=fail
    fi
done
test "$status" = pass && echo all tests passed
}
```

The awk will read from stdin (which the exec redirects from the file; personally I would skip that line and have the caller direct input appropriately) and splits the input into records of one paragraph each.  A "paragraph" here means that the records are separated by blank lines (the lines must be truly blank, and cannot contain whitespace).  Awk then parses each record and prints the 3rd, 6th, and 9th field on a single line.  This is a bit fragile, but for the shown input those fields represent length, message, and md hash, respectively.  All the awk is doing is rearranging the input so that it is one record per line.  Once the data is in a more readable format, a subshell reads the data one line at a time, parsing it into the variables named "len", "msg", and "md".  The do loop processes once per line of input, spewing the rather verbose message "passed" with each test it runs (I would remove that, but retained it here for consistency with the original script), and setting the status if any tests fail.  The braces are necessary to ensure that the value of the variable status is retained after the do loop terminates.

Comment: +1. you might add an explanation about why the braces are required.

Comment: Is there supposed to be any of the code I previously provided tacked onto that? As it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: No, this is a complete script.  A likely source of error is the format of the input file: is there truly a blank line between records?  A line with nothing but whitespace on it is *not* a blank line.  What does "doesn't seem to be working" mean?  Add echo statements as necessary to debug the issue.

Comment: No, the separators are blank lines, and it's not looping through the whole file, which is what I need it to do. It's working perfectly for the first instance though, so thanks for that.

Comment: @WilliamPursell So, if I run it with the exec line in, it only runs through the loop once, and if I take it out and directly call it, it doesn't print $3,$6,$9 it, instead does $1,$2,$3 no matter what I I assign them to, and I don't know why. Thoughts?

Comment: What do you get if you remove everything including and after the `|`?  That is, run nothing but the awk. IOW, delete everything after the awk, but keep the awk line and delete the '| {' at the end of it.

Answer (score 2):

The following code,

```
inputfile="../../Tests/shabittestvectors/SHA1ShortMsg.rsp"

while read -r len msg md
do
        echo got: LEN:$len  MSG:$msg MD:$md

        #cypher=$(./cyassl hash -sha -i $msg -l $len)
        #continue as you wish

done < <(perl -00 -F'[\s=]+|\n' -lE 'say qq{$F[1] $F[3] $F[5]}' < "$inputfile")
```

for your input data, produces:

```
got: LEN:0 MSG:00 MD:da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
got: LEN:1 MSG:00 MD:bb6b3e18f0115b57925241676f5b1ae88747b08a
got: LEN:2 MSG:40 MD:ec6b39952e1a3ec3ab3507185cf756181c84bbe2
```

Comment: What do you mean the next code? This is the most helpful code so far, but I'm not quite sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @ChangeJar Maybe shoud be "_the following code_ ... for you input data produces..." - my english not my native...

Comment: @jmm666 I can't upvote until I have 15 reputation, and I currently only have 11. I also haven't completely gotten it figured out yet, so I haven't selected an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your input data is in order you can have this with a simplified `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOOP=10
PASS=0

FILE='../../Tests/shabittestvectors/SHA1ShortMsg.rsp'

for (( I = 1; I <= LOOP; ++I )); do
    read -r LEN && read -r MSG && read -r MD || break

    echo "$LEN"
    echo "$MSG"

    MD=${MD:0:-1}
    CIPHER=$(exec ./cyassl hash -sha -i "$MSG" -l "$LEN")

    echo "$MD"
    echo "$CIPHER"

    if [[ $MD == "$CIPHER" ]]; then
        echo "PASSED"
        (( ++PASS ))
    fi
done < <(exec awk '/Len =/,/Msg =/,/MD =/ { print $3 }' "$FILE")

[[ PASS -eq LOOP ]] && echo "All Tests Successful."
```

Just make sure you don't run it as `sh` e.g. `sh script.sh`. `bash script.sh` most likely.